# AVR/embedded: Normalizing vectors in a fast manner?

Tags: c, performance, normalization, avr, approximation

I have wasted quite some days fighting with my 16mhz 8bit AVR (mega 2560).

The goal is to normalize value I am receiving (accelerometer, magnetometer etc).
The values are 16 bit signed (int16) and after I want a float from 0.0f-1.0f
I am using this for a 3d IMU.

Common approach :

```
int32_t tmp = (int32_t)a*a+b*b+c*c;
float magnitude = sqrt(tmp);
float a_v = a / magnitude;
float b_v = b / magnitude;
float c_v = c / magnitude;
```

A faster approach:

```
int32_t tmp = (int32_t)a*a+b*b+c*c;
float imagnitude = InvSqrt(tmp); // like the 'tricky' one for ID software quake source
float a_v = a * imagnitude;
float b_v = b * imagnitude;
float c_v = c * imagnitude;
```

The second one has some advantages as it uses an aproximiation instead of the 1/sqrt (but there are also aproximated sqrts) and it requires 3 multiplications instead of divisions which are good as the AVR supports MUL but not DIV.
On the other hand, it's very slow anyway due to floating point and 32 bit calculations.

Such a function typically takes 1-2 milliseconds which has a huge impact on my code which tries to solve a lot of additional tasks and normalizations in a cycle that is supposed to last 2.4ms max

I digged around a lot and tried many different approximations and ideas but whatever I tried, the code is way too slow in execution.

Maybe there is another approach to normalize my sensor values..

**Update for people with my special problem (accelerometer magnitude):**
Without floting point and sqrt I am working at this right now: (ignore the additional casts:)
int16 cal[] holds the calibrated accelerometer value for the 3 axes.

```
int16 average_sq_1g = CONST_1G / 256;
uint32_t work = (int32_t)((int32_t)cal[0]*cal[0] + (int32_t)cal[1]*cal[1] + (int32_t)cal[2]*cal[2])/256;
work = work * 100L / average_sq_1g;
attitude.acc_magnitude = work;
```

This is quite specialized for my cause as I am working to get the magnitude of acceleration and I know the value I receive for 1G (around 16000)
So the formula (X^2+Y^2+Z^2)*100/1G^2 returns me the magnitude (100 = no additional acceleration and can be done without using floats.
I did not check for the performance difference but it should be a lot faster.

Comment: Why use floating point at all? Can you use fixed-point (e.g. Q15) instead?

Comment: The first line needs more casts. The first multiplication is 1nt32_t, but the other two are only between ints. Overflow could occur.

Comment: UncleO: I doubt there would be an overflow, the compiler should treat the whole operation correctly. I use code similar to that and it works fine without overflow.
@anatolyg: I am currently changing my whole code to integer 32 bit as I could not get it to work faster. I am not sure how much fixed point would help, there is no fixed floating point support on AVR-GCC afaik.

Comment: SCNR: +1 for the quake source InvSqrt() reference

Comment: @UncleO: All the multiplications are between `int`, not `int16_t`, due to promotion.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, Ben. In AVR, `int` is `int16_t`, as far as I know. That's the reason for my comment. I assumed the two mults would occur as ints, and not be promoted to `long int` or `int32_t` until the addition. John says his testing shows otherwise.

Comment: @John, fixed point uses the integer hardware, you don't need special support for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use fix point arithmetics.

scale your input by a reasonable amount of bits and use integer operations. (there are also algorithms for integer sqare root calculation)

for example if you have value range from -10m to 10m and require at least mm resolution i would add 11 bits (scaled with 2048)

```
#define VEC_SHIFT 11
#define VEC_SCALE (1 << (VEC_SHIFT))
int16_t a =  7 * VEC_SCALE;
int16_t b =  3 * VEC_SCALE;
int16_t c = 10 * VEC_SCALE;

// calculations have to be done in larger data type so they do not overflow
int32_t snorm = (int32_t)a * a + (int32_t)b*b + (int32_t)c*c;  // snorm now is scaled by VEC_SCALE*VEC_SCALE (2*VEC_SHIFT)
int16_t norm = intsqrt(snorm); // norm is scaled with VEC_SCALE

// since norm and a,b,c is in VEC_SCALE, you have to scale up the divident so that one VEC_SCALE is chanceled out by division 
int16_t as =  (((int32_t)a) * VEC_SCALE )/norm;
int16_t bs =  (((int32_t)b) * VEC_SCALE )/norm;
int16_t cs =  (((int32_t)c) * VEC_SCALE )/norm;
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed point is definitely the way to go. The only difficulty is to get the precision preserved.

In this case - if the precision is important - I would use the following rather fast algorithm:

- extract the exponents of each floating point number (bits 23..30 of the float)
- save the sign of each value (bit 31) for further use
- extract the 15 most significant bits of the mantissa (bits 8..22), add one '1' to the left

This may sound complicated, but it can accomplished, e.g.,

```
sign = b3 & 0x80;
exponent = b3 << 1;
if (b2 & 0x80)
  exponent |= 1;
else
  b2 |= 0x80;
mantissa = join_to_word(b1, b2);
```

where `b0`..`b3`are the single octets of the float (`b3` being the one with sign, see IEEE754 float structure). The oring of `b2` by 0x80 is due to the hidden bit in the floating point representation. The function `join_to_word` is something to combine the two bytes into a word. This should not result in a single instruction in the machine code, as only the compiler needs to know where the two octets reside. (One way to accomplish this is to use unions.)

Now that we know the exponents:

- find the biggest exponent
- calculate the square of the mantissa for that number
- shift to the right by 2
- for the other two mantissas

  - shift to the right by the exponent difference (i.e. if the largest exponent is 17, a number with exponent 14 needs to be shifted right by 17-14=3)
  - if the difference is >= 7, forget this number (both optimizes a bit and handles zero-exponents)
  - otherwise, square the mantissa, shift to the right by 2, and add to the square calculated above
- take the square root of the sum of squares

So, at this point we have:

- the norm with 15-16 significant bits
- the absolute values of the components with 16 significant bits

What remains in the integer domain is to perform the division by shifting the absolute values 15 bits to the left and divide them by the norm. The resulting vectors are then scaled by 2^16.

Then we have the conversion to the floating point left. The basic steps for each number

- if the number is zero, fill the fp by zeros, otherwise perform the following steps
- exponent is 127+16 = 142
- if the most significant bit is not one, shift the mantissa left until the highest bit is one, decrement the exponent at each shift
- reset the highest bit of the mantissa
- if the lowest bit of the exponent is 1, or it to the highest bit of the mantissa
- shift the exponent right by one
- OR the sign back to the exponent octet
- assemble the fp number from the exponent, mantissa, and a byte of zeros

The whole algorithm should run in a few hundred clock cycles.

If you are really in a hurry, the first thing is to look at the assembly code. There may be unnecessary library calls, unnecessary zero bytes, etc. depending on how you have written the code, and what your C compiler thinks or does not think. The second step is to write this routine in assembly, but usually it can be avoided.

But there is one thing for you to consider: is it absolutely necessary to use floating points at all? They are slow.